# How do I find out what App just connected to internet?

Tags: internet-connection, log

How do I tell the ubuntu to report what app connected to the internet?

I am learning of CLI programs that report connections but an App connected to the internet and the description of it disappeared from the Terminal window before I had a chance to examine it.

I looked at the firewall log but it say nothing about what Apps are connecting to the internet. So how do I learn what App connected to the internet in the last 10 minutes or so?

Why is there no log report of what Apps are connecting to internet? How do I get this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no log like that. If there were it would be several gigs in size. Your best bet is to run something like `iftop` or `nethogs` neither of which is installed by default.

If your really, really paranoid, then you could `cat /proc/net/tcp` but this doesn't log.

There's also `netstat -tapn` but again that's only "what is connected right now".

Then there's also [this article](http://toastresearch.com/2011/04/09/packet-logging-with-iptables/) that will tell you how to log outgoing connections via iptables.

Again, this is likely not that smart of an idea, the log will be huge.